# Import python module in bash script

Tags: python, bash

I have python 3 project that looks like this

```
-Myproject
     -Mymodule 
         -file.py
```

Inside file.py I have a function myfunction().

I want to write a bash script, myscript.sh where first I import the file.py and call the function myfunction(), when calling the ./myscript.sh from the terminal. 
Any suggestions how can I import the module?

Comment: Do you want to use the output returned by the function or just call the function?

Comment: Are you asking how you write command-line programs in Python?  Because you can't import a Python module into a shell script.

Comment: I would like to have the returned output from the function and later display it to the user! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly "import a Python module and call a Python function" from a bash script since this will make it a Python script.

What you could do is change `file.py` so it accepts CLI parameters which it will handle and execute the appropriate functions. Then your bash script could look something like

```
#!/bin/bash

./file.py myfunction
```

Comment: I am up with it.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment that you want to capture the function output in your bash script, you'll need 2 things.

Add this at the bottom of `file.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myfunction()
```

Make sure `myfunction()` prints to stdout.

Then call it in the bash script:

```
output=$(python file.py)
```

Comment: I want to pass parameters to myfunction, which I get from the user input in the bash script. Therefore I have problem with calling the whole file.py ?

Comment: @mitevva_t Basically you have to access [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to get CLI parameters. But this can get ugly quickly if you add more params, in that case look at the built-in [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse) module. You could also consider the [Click](http://click.pocoo.org) community library, but that may be overkill.